# What's the proper way to optimize this Django code with select_related/prefetch_related?

Tags: django, django-select-related

I have a simple situation with two models and a ForeignKey:

```
class Image(models.Model):
   # Stuff here

   def iotd_date(self):
       iotd = self.image_of_the_day.all()
       if iotd: 
          return iotd[0].date
       return None

class ImageOfTheDay(models.Model):
   date = models.DateField()
   image = models.ForeignKey(Image, related_name = 'iotd')
```

Whenever I do `{{some_image.iotd_date}}` in a template, that hits the database.

How can I prefetch that information? I've tried `.select_related('iotd')` (the `related_name`) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out: `prefetch_related` does the trick, actually.